# Привязка к кнопке функции запуска другого скрипта на tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужна помощь, пишу интерфейс для проги нa python tkinter, хочу сделать, чтобы по нажатию кнопки запускался скрипт отдельный, но в том же проекте pycharm, я понял что можно привязать команду к кнопке с помощью функции(def), но не понимаю как вложить туда метод запуска другого скрипта, пробовал subprocess и os.system, постоянно выдает ошибку, что нет файла в директории или что модуля нет, даже если я все вводил верно (в плане синтаксиса и пути к файлу) то все равно файл не находился или (как мне посоветовали на форумах метод который в коде) выдает:
TypeError: system() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
вот код

```
import os
from tkinter import *



def script():
    os.system('python','script1')
    return

root = Tk()

root['bg'] = 'grey'
root.title('tiktok_register')
root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 1)
root.geometry('640x400')

root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


n1 = Button(width=10, height=5,
           command=script,bg='white', text="start")
n1.pack(side=BOTTOM)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Проще импортировать другой скрипт, в обработчике нажатия вызвать метод из этого скрипта (напрямую, без os.system)

Comment: import script1
def script():
    script1.metod()

Answer (score 0):

напишите вместо os.system('python', 'script1'); os.system(('python', 'script1')). Возможно вы еще забыли написать расширение файла script1, то есть script1.py

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from tkinter import *



def script():
    os.system('py')
    os.system('script.py')
    return

root = Tk()

root['bg'] = 'grey'
root.title('tiktok_register')
root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 1)
root.geometry('640x400')

root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


n1 = Button(width=10, height=5,
           command=script,bg='white', text="start")
n1.pack(side=BOTTOM)



root.mainloop()
```

Мы указали какого формата файл нам нужен и имя этого файла